# How to write to a batch file to tell it to write to another batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

How to write to a batch file a command which itself writes to another file. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this

```
File1.bat
echo abc >> op.txt

File2.bat
echo abc >> op.txt >> main.txt
```

I'd like to following statement to be the content of main.txt when I run File2.bat but that didn't happen

```
main.txt
echo abc >>op.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to echo the `>` character, you need to escape it with `^`.

If the contents of `File2.bat` are:

```
echo echo abc ^>^> op.txt >> main.txt
```

then after running `File2.bat`, the contents of `main.txt` will be:

```
echo abc >> op.txt
```

[Read more about escape characters.](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure at 100% if it will work but I think what you have to do is:

```
echo (

Your Code

) > Directory\Batchfile.bat
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! When posting an answer please make sure it works. This time we checked it for you and it doesn't work. Please edit and make it a working answer, otherwise it will get removed